# Wamp Server 2.5 (PHP5.5) Cant activate sqlsrv module

Tags: php, wamp, sqlsrv

I just updated my Wamp Server and got a problem now.

My SQLSRV extension wont get loaded correctly.
I dont know where the problem is exactly because i dont get any errors on startup. Also the error log is clean. There is just a little red triangle instead of a check in the php extension list:

[image: screenshot]

Some Information:

- Windows Server 2012 x64
- Wamp 2.5 32BIT
- PHP5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Warning Icon means one of 2 things :-

Either the `extension=` line is in your php.ini but the dll it points to is not in your `\ext` folder

Or the dll exists in the ext folder but not in your php.ini

Which one is it in your case. If you updated WAMPServer the SQLServer dll does not come with any PHP install by default, so you will have to download it from the microsoft site.

Comment: Hell Yeah! You were right dude! I edited the wrong php.ini... why ever the php.ini in php folder and the php.ini i can open in wamp interface is different .. but thanks alot =)

Comment: Because it is useful to be able to configure PHP CLI and PHP in Apache seperately.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, i still cant understand this error. sure i know that i have to download the SQL driver manually. And i know only the "SQLSRV31.EXE" driver is working with Win Server 2K12. I downloaded this one and copied all php5.5 drivers into the /ext folder. Then i copied the name of the dll`s and added them to the php.ini:

http://fs1.directupload.net/images/141206/pkij993j.png

I will tryout installing the older wamp version with php5.4 included. May this will work =)

Comment: Hmm.... now i installed Wamp Server 2.4 with php5.4.12, there is no triangle. but there it is till not possible to enable the modules. I can remove the semicolon hundrets of times or click on the module in wamp inter face hundrets of times (service restarts included) but the extension wont get a hook... i really hate it. older versions working well but do not support windows server 2012...... why i only get problems like this with MS?

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same thing happened to you. I tried many things but didn't work at all. I installed all the things required for Wamp like Microsoft visual basics 2012 but it still didn't worked.

This is the most important thing, for me this problem happened because i download wamp server 2.5 from the official wamp server site. http://www.wampserver.com/Mk
DON'T DO IT. it's totally a shit. then i download wamp server 2.4(old version) from this site called FIRE HORSE. this is the link http://www.filehorse.com/download-wampserver-32/

I downloaded and installed wamp server 2.4 from this site and it worked perfectly fine. and i also installed the latest Joomla version 3.4.5 in wamp server. Now i'm using it 100% fine. Many thanks for FIRE HORSE site. 
I hope you all will find this useful and don't forget to tell me if i'm wrong because i'm still in learning progress i just shared my experience with you all. thank you.